# Alternating non-sequential row colors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I'll start fresh. I have a table pulled from a remote server. The table has white odd rows and grey even rows. I've hidden some rows:

```
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R1';}).text('Row1'); //white
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R2';}).text('Row2'); //grey
$('tr:nth-child(3)').hide();                                            //white
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R4';}).text('Row4'); //grey
$('tr:nth-child(5)').hide();                                            //white
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R6';}).text('Row6'); //grey
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text()=='R7';}).text('Row7'); //white
```

Now my table rows no longer alternate but is instead white, grey, grey, grey, white. How do I make them alternate again? Creating a class like: `$("tr").filter(":even").addClass("even");` + css `tr.even td{background-color: blue;}` makes it white, blue, blue, blue, white so it still doesn't alternate.

I can do this `$('tr:nth-child(4)').each(function(i){ $(this).find('td').css('background-color', 'white');});` and it works white, grey, WHITE, grey, white. But there's a catch! Row 4 has red cells that I want to remain red. The code above overrides the red cells to white.

The style from the server is:

```
<script src="remoteserver/sorttable.js"></script>
<style type = "text/css">';
    td.datacellone{
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
    }
    th.datacellheader{
        background-color: #6A5ACD;
    }
    td.alert{
        background-color: #FF0000;
    }
    td.orange{
        background-color: #FFA500;
    }
    td.green{
        background-color: #008000;
    }
</style>
```

I want this red alert color to remain red while the rows alternate to white and grey.

Comment: Can you get the server to send it with a `!important` ?

Comment: Using `!important` is a very bad idea

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be is to apply the classes over again..

```
 var $table = $('table');
 $('tr:even', $table).addClass('even');
 $('tr:odd', $table).addClass('odd');

  //Remove 1 td

  $('tr', $table).removeClass('even odd'); // Remove both the classes
  $('tr:even', $table).addClass('even');
  $('tr:odd', $table).addClass('odd');

**EDIT**
```

If you can change the styles that are being added, replace

```
td.alert{ background-color: #FF0000; }
```

with

```
tr td.alert{ background-color: #FF0000; }
```

**OR**

```
tr.odd td.alert, tr.eventd.alert, { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

Comment: Hi Sushanth. Thank you for your suggestion. Your approach may be too simple for me to understand. I pasted your code after mine and nothing happened. Do I need to add anything in my css? Please elaborate.

Comment: you would need to define the CSS classes to your style sheet or where ever you are defining them

Comment: nnnnnn's suggestion works. His is similar to yours except the `:visible` is what makes it work. I still need your help in retaining red cells since the alternating grey and white rows are overriding the red cells to white and/or grey.

Comment: How are you defining the styles for the other td's .. Look's like a specificity issue

Comment: This is all I have in my css as far as td is concerned `td{padding: 0.5em; border: 1px solid red;}`.

Comment: Do I create a class "alert", then add the css `tr td.alert{ background-color: #FF0000; }`? If so, how do I create that class?

Comment: The class alert is already in your CSS  `<style type = "text/css">` . Just replace that style with the one above .. Or just add this to your head after the server script in the question `<style type = "text/css"> tr.odd td.alert, tr.eventd.alert, { background-color: #FF0000; } </style>`

Comment: No it's not. That style is being pulled from a remote server.

Comment: Then add the one from the previous comment into your head section of your page

Comment: I added the style to my head and that CSS which is the same as the CSS from the server so it's overriding MY CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have classes called `even` and `odd`, try something like this:

```
var $trs = $('tr').removeClass('even odd').filter(':visible');
$trs.filter(':even').addClass('even');
$trs.filter(':odd').addClass('odd');
```

That is, remove any existing `even` and `odd` classes from the tr elements, then use the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to just process the ones that you didn't hide.

Demo (that also shows how individual red cells are not affected by the row classes): http://jsfiddle.net/J5DqP/1/

Comment: Hi nnnnnn. Your suggestion actually works with my added css `tr.even td{background-color: #C0C0C0;}` `tr.odd td{background-color: #FFFFFF;}`. My rows are alternating again, except now we need to make the red cells remain red. How do we do this?

Comment: I've updated my demo to show that you can retain red cells. But how do _you_ set them to red in the first place? Also, why not just `tr.even {background-color...`? You don't really need the `td` in the CSS selector. CSS _cascades,_ so if you apply the odd and even just to the rows and then apply the red just to the cells that might fix your problem.

Comment: Ok I'll elaborate a bit. I don't set the cells to red in the first place. I am pulling a table from a remote server whose cells change color green,orange,red depending on the cell data. If cell data is 100% the cell is green, if it's 80% it's orange, and if 60% it's red. Your demo is hard coding the red cells. I can't do that, since the cell data changes frequently. As for omitting the `tr.odd {background-color...`, the alternating rows cease to work. But I get that css should cascade but it's not.

Comment: I updated my original post to add the style that the remote server is applying. `<script src="remoteserver/sorttable.js"></script> <style type = "text/css">';`...

Comment: That should still work as per my demo. Note in my demo that the grey and white odd and even class apply to _tr_ elements, but the red class applies to _td_ elements. The styles you added to your question are also for _td_ elements, so they should work the same way.

Comment: But td 4 `$('td').eq(4).addClass('red');` can change to green,orange,red at any time. In fact, all td can change color at any time. How do I code this? `$('td').eq(4).addClass('red');` `$('td').eq(4).addClass('orange');` `$('td').eq(4).addClass('green');` `$('td').eq(5).addClass('red');` `$('td').eq(5).addClass('orange');` `$('td').eq(5).addClass('green');`, etc. seems redundant.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter how you code the cell colour changes if you apply the row shading actually on the rows and not on the cells within the rows.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little slow. I'm not sure what you mean. Right now td 5 is green (I have the table from the remote server showing td 5 is green and my modified table on another server that doesn't show the green). I did your demo `$('td').eq(5).addClass('green');` and added css `td.green{background-color: #008000;}` but it doesn't show green. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can we set a condition so that if a cell is green to keep it green? Something like `var filter_green = function(){ return $(this).css('background-color') == 'green'};` then `$('td').not(filter_green);`? These codes don't work though. But just an idea.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. There must be something else going on here if you're still having problems. Can you provide a demo of your problem at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nTtyd/. First time using jsfiddle. Please have a look. The table is being pulled from a remote server and the table also has its own css which is `<script src="remoteserver/sorttable.js"></script> <style type = "text/css">'; td.datacellone{ background-color: #C0C0C0; } th.datacellheader{ background-color: #6A5ACD; } td.alert{ background-color: #FF0000; } td.orange{ background-color: #FFA500; } td.green{ background-color: #008000; } </style> </script>`. But if I use my own css the server's css is overridden with white and grey.

Comment: _My point is that it doesn't matter how you code the cell colour changes if you apply the row shading actually on the rows and not on the cells within the rows_. I did what you did on your demo `tr.even{background-color: #C0C0C0;}` and you're right the colored cells remain but now the rows do not alternate white and grey. Originally I had `tr.even td{background-color: #C0C0C0;}` and the rows alternate but override the colored cells. I know what you mean now by applying the row shading on rows only and not cells, but it's still not giving me the results I need.

Comment: Should I add a class or something to my hidden rows? If so, how is it coded?